Noise at timing chain or engin zone
I have tiida 2010 nissan 1.6 hr16de
Nowadays ai started to hear noise frome the engine or timing chain zone
I couldn't realise where it
This noise isn't present at idle or 1000 rpm
It starts just above 1000rpm and disappears totally at about ~2800rpm
So when I'm in the city it's always present
When I'm on highways where my speed is 120-130 km/h for 3000 to 3500 rpm it's not present
I asked someone he told me it's vvt solenoid
What do you think ,, help me
Thank you
The sound is here :
Nb : i changed the timing chain kit vefore 4 months without problems
https://youtu.be/rQrTdpx33EE

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!
